# Keycloak - Extend refresh_token expire time after requesting a new access token

Tags: node.js, jwt, keycloak, keycloak-js

I'm trying to extend the expiration time of refresh tokens, after using one.

Let's imagine that my current `access_token` has expired. In order to have a new `access_token`, I make a request using my refresh token, `grant_type='refresh_token'&refresh_token=refreshToken`, to Keycloak that gives me a new `access_token` and a new `refresh_token`. The problem is that this new `refresh_token` has the same expiration date as the previous one. This means that I'll have to reenter my credentials some time after my login in order to extend my refresh token expire date.

What I intend to do is to only logout from my application if the user doesn't login for a given amount of time.

Note: If I change the `scope` to be `offline_access` there is no expiration date on the token. I could use this but this means that this token will live forever. See also:

- https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/extend-expiry-of-refresh-token-on-every-usage/19881
- https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/refresh-token-expiration-time-does-not-renew-on-usage/21115

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I tested  Keycloak V 22.0.1 , The new refresh token's exp (Expiration Time) claim in a JWT. it is not same as old refresh token exp. It is extended 30 minutes from new "iat" (Issued At).

Comment: @BenchVue I'm using Keycloak v20.0.2 and its Rest API. The `iat` changes when I refresh the tokens, but `exp` doesn't get extended. I'm currently making a request to `${baseURL}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token` with `grant_type: 'refresh_token'`. Did you make a similar request?

Comment: I've created a clean realm, and the new refresh token has an extended lifetime. So I probably changed a setting on my main realm without noticing the impact...

Comment: @BenchVue I think I figured it out: I had SSO Session Idle = SSO Session Max, now I have SSO Session Idle < SSO Session Max. Would like your opinion before answering this post, please

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how to test SSO session. I did test same as you test to get refresh token by ${baseURL}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token with grant_type: 'refresh_token'